# Mouse.move: how do I move the mouse to the center of a screen?

Tags: programming, keyboard, mouse

I have a program operating in full screen mode. I would like to move the mouse to the center of the screen. Is this something I can do with the functionality of Mouse.h?
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/mouse/

Mouse.move moves fixed increments. maybe I should change the mouse start location in the computer program.

my issue, is that the "circuit playground" is the primary interface, using the accelerator for position. Once the computer is running the software, the Arduino has to be centered to work properly.

alternatively, is there a command I can send that could center the mouse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of working with HID mice - absolute and relative. The Arduino `Mouse` library only works in relative mode, but you want absolute.

There's another library **https://github.com/NicoHood/HID** which does do considerably more than the normal Arduino HID libraries - including "Absolute Mouse".

Comment: hey cool, samd21 support!
Thanks @Majenko